# What's wrong with While? Is it possible to use double While in a single code input?

Tags: procedural-programming

**I am supposed to get 2 in the output, but it is still -3 instead.**

```
ClearAll[t, n];
n = -10;
While[True, If[n^2 + n - 6 == 0, Break[]]; n++];
t = n;
While[True, If[t^2 + t - 6 == 0, Break[]]; t++];
t
```

*Is it possible to abort the 1st root(-3) and get 2nd root (2) with While loop code here?*

Comment: it works OK as expected. because `t=-3` before second loop and so second loops exists right away and so `t` do not change? why do you think `t` should be `2` ?

Comment: @Nasser how can I make second loop work?

Comment: If you mean by `make second loop work` is to get `-3` again for `t`, then you need to reset `n` back to `-10` again before you assign it to `t` since `n` has changed after the first loop has finished. But may be you can clarify why you expected second loop to return `2` in the question itself, that would be best.

Comment: @Nasser. If it works in the way you have said, then n=-10 should not be considered in 1st loop. And the output should be -10.

Comment: n++ works by incrementing n. try this `n = 0; n++; n` and now is `1` and no longer zero. But it is possible I do not understand what the issue you are having in all of this and what exactly is the problem here.

Comment: @Nasser, I wanna get the second root that meet the criteria I set `n^2 + n - 6 == 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanna get the second root that meet the criteria I set n^2 + n - 6 == 0

In this case you could do

```
ClearAll[t, n];
n = -10;
While[True, If[n^2 + n - 6 == 0, Break[]]; n++];
t = n + 1;
While[True, If[t^2 + t - 6 == 0, Break[]]; t++];
t
```

Which gives `2`.

Or you could also just do

```
ClearAll[n];
Solve[n^2 + n - 6 == 0, n]
```

But I am sure you knew about the `Solve` command and was trying to do it another way.

Comment: I know `Solve`  command can do it much easier. But I wanna test how `While` is working here. Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly different way to do it is this

```
ClearAll[t, n];
n = -11;
While[True, n++; If[n^2 + n - 6 == 0, Break[]];];
t = n;
While[True, t++; If[t^2 + t - 6 == 0, Break[]];];
t
```